# Create Form Command Button calling a UserForm

Tags: button, userform, type-mismatch, commandbutton

I'd like to create a form control button with which I could display a UserForm when clicking the button. Unfortunately I have the following error message popping up: "Compile Error: Type Mismatch". 
Any thoughts ?

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(230.25, 57, 153, 96.75).Select
Selection.OnAction = UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: Apologies, I didn't even say hello ! Hello then ! :)

Comment: I don't think you can put VBA code in the OnAction. It should be a Sub that OnAction can utilize.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a separate Sub to launch the UserForm1.

Try avoid using ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet if not an AddIn.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateButton()
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(230.25, 57, 153, 96.75)
        .Caption = "Launch UserForm 1"
        .Font.Size = 14
        .OnAction = "ShowUserForm1" ' ## A ##
        .Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub ShowUserForm1() ' Sub Name must match ## A ##
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```